# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when reloading the project in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I switch to other branches and I click on reload project button, I receive the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error and vs is not able to load the project.

I am using vs2022 17.3.4

[image]
[image]

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be because some of your projects have migrated to the new .NET project SDK, but your solution file (.sln) is not updated.

This can be fixed by updating your solution file:
Highlight your solution in the Solution Explorer and click "Save {solution name}.sln" in the File menu. Then restart Visual Studio and try reloading your project again.

Comment: Somebody out there who knows, if there is a similar action in Rider?